# Allow access to a type of resource but deny access to specific instance of the resource in Apache Shiro

Tags: authorization, shiro

I have a question regarding allowing access to a resource but deny access to some instances of this resource in Apache Shiro.

Say I have a resource Reports that can be viewed or edited and two users Tom and Katie.

If i'm not mistaken in Shiro i can give Tom access to edit all Reports by giving him the following permission:

"report:edit"

Katie should also be able to edit all reports except Report x which she should only be able to view.

So i want to express something like this:

"report:edit"
"report:view:x"

As far as I've understood from Shiro it's all about permissive permissions and this could be expressed as "report:edit:y,z,..." and "report:view:x" but if you have a lot of reports it's not very practical or readable.

Any suggestions how this can be achieved in Shiro or using other methods?

Thank you,
Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create subclass the WildcardPermission class and implement your own implies method to write your own denied implementation.

The override WildcardPermissionResolver to return your permission implementation instead of the standard one.

Then you can configure it to be used globally in shiro.ini:

```
globalPermissionResolver = com.foo.bar.authz.MyPermissionResolver
```

See documentation here: https://shiro.apache.org/authorization.html#Authorization-Configuringaglobal%7B%7BPermissionResolver%7D%7D